# What to use for node_prepare in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am converting a module from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. I have come across a Drupal 6 functional call named node_prepare and I am not sure what needs to be done to make this work with Drupal 7. What should this function be replaced with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to replace it with anything as it happens, you can just remove it.

All that function does is prepare the node body for display. Since the body is a field in Drupal 7, all that processing is done elsewhere, and it's not something you need to invoke manually any more.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it easy. All I then need to do is implement hook_view() to actually display the node as I would like it to be.